# FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code:

```
self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore
                               accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSString *appID = @"356775877779749"; //The app ID issued by Facebook
NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        appID, ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                        @[@"email"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                        nil];

[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
     if (granted)
     {
         NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
         //it will always be the last object with single sign on
         self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];


         ACAccountCredential *facebookCredential = [self.facebookAccount credential];
         NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];
         NSLog(@"Successfully logged in. Access Token: %@", accessToken);


         FBSDKAccessToken* AccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
         NSLog(@"%@", AccessToken);
         [self newFacebookLogin];
     } else {
         //Failed
         NSLog(@"error getting permission: %@",e);
     }
 }];
```

I log in with the code above. For some reason `NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken]` stores the access token correctly but              `FBSDKAccessToken* AccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` does not.

Is there any way to covert the `NSString *accessToken` to type `FBSDKAccessToken`?

Comment: Why do you need to do that, if you are using Facebook SDK in your project? Why you are not integrating FBLogin ?

Comment: I am integrating FB login but I want to avoid the need to go to safari. I can do this if I can get the access token to log them in natively

Comment: I think you must know Facebook SDK does that by self, it checks whether native FB A/C is present or not , if not then only it shows the login popup.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, and it was due to me not setting `enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange` on `FBSDKProfile`. Not sure why it doesn't do this by default.

```
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:TRUE];
```

Or for Swift

```
FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case I forgot to add below line in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Other Reason is if you call **[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]** before **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** that it will alway return **nil**

I hope it will work for you...

Answer (score -1):

You can reach the accessToken string representation by calling tokenString parameter in FBSDKAccessToken.

```
 FBSDKAccessToken* AccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];

 NSString *tokenString = AccessToken.tokenString;
```

to explicitly create accessToken, there is only one method in a [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/) and it is:

```
- (instancetype)
initWithTokenString:    (NSString *)tokenString
permissions:    (NSArray *)permissions
declinedPermissions:    (NSArray *)declinedPermissions
appID:  (NSString *)appID
userID: (NSString *)userID
expirationDate: (NSDate *)expirationDate
refreshDate:    (NSDate *)refreshDate
NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

however there is also discussion part for this and states that:

*This initializer should only be used for advanced apps that manage tokens explicitly. Typical login flows only need to use `FBSDKLoginManager` along with `+currentAccessToken`.*